# FAT: List all files in a directory

Tags: c, api, fat

I'm using [Chan's FAT library](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) that seems to provide a standard FAT filesystem API. The API doesn't seem to directly offer to list all the files in a given  directory.

What is the standard way to list all files in a directory given access to a standard FAT API? Is there a special file (some "directory table"?) that I can access using `f_read()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [f_opendir](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/opendir.html) and [f_readdir](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/readdir.html):

> The f_readdir function reads directory entries in sequence. All items in the directory can be read by calling f_readdir function repeatedly. When all directory entries have been read and no item to read, the function returns a null string into f_name[] member without any error. When a null pointer is given to the FileInfo, the read index of the directory object will be rewinded.